Paramterizing the surface on the intersection of $x+z=a$ and interior of $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$
So I am trying to verify Stokes' theorem for $\vec{F}=y\hat{i}+z\hat{j}+x\hat{k}$ where the curve $C$ is on the intersection of $x+z=a$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$. Solving these equations yields the curve $2(x-a/2)^2+y^2=a^2/2$ which I have parametrized as $x=\frac{a}{2}(1+\cos\theta)$, $y=\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}\sin\theta$, $z=\frac{a}{2}(1-\cos\theta)$ with $0\le\theta<2\pi$. The line integral $\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$ now evaluates to $-\frac{a^2\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.
Now I want to take the surface as the intersection of $x+z=a$ and the interior of $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and prove that the surface integral $\int(\nabla\times \vec{F})\cdot d\vec{s}  $ evaluates to the same value. For this reason, I want the parametric equation of this disk. But what can it be?

Allow the radius to change in your parametrization of the boundary:
$$
x=\frac{a}{2}+\frac{r}{2}\cos\theta, y=\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\theta,z=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{r}{2}\cos\theta)
$$
with $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq r\leq a$. Obviously this parametrization is not bijective at the origin, but that shouldn't cause a problem.

$z+x$ needn't be $a$ for this parametrization. So how is it correct?

@MathArt where do you see that $x+z=a$? I see that $x+z=r$ and $r\in(0,a)$

@NinadMunshi: Exactly. If $x+z=r<a$ then the point (x,y,z) will not lie on the surface which is a subset of the plane $x+z=a$. So this parametrization isn't correct.

Apologies, I meant to keep $a/2$ as a constant. Have edited...
